# How to call javascript function after submit button click event mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have search form with submit button on it i want to make every textbox after submit to be readonly

```js
 <input id="search"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn1" type="submit" value="searh" />
```

that code work fine if i change the type to button
any idea to make it work as a submit type

```js
 var button = document.getElementById('search');
    button.onclick = function () {

        let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            inputs[i].readOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is of submit type, you can add an onclick function to initiate the Javascript. This can be seen in the following code:

```js
function search() {

        let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            inputs[i].readOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <input id="search"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn1" type="submit" onclick="search()" value="Search" />
```

When the button is clicked, it will initiate the search() function.